# Some Problems About Jquery Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im up with a question..

I have my main file, the index.php, and inside of index im importing jquery 2.0.3.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The main problem is because i have other file in the server, it is called website.php, and inside i have imported jquery 1.8.3.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, if i take off the second librarie, the all site works correctly, but one plugin doesn't work, but if i take out the second librarie, the whole site works on but the other plugin dont!

Sorry for bad english, but the problem is because of the jquery conflict..
I already made some research, and use the jQuery.noConflict(), but still doesn't work!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which is other plugin?

Comment: Thanks!
The plugin is: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/

Comment: jQuery 1.8.3 is fairly old, there may be a backwards compatibility issue. Run the plugin through Chrome with the developer toolbar on and find the lines in question that break and fix the plugin. Remember 2.x.x isn't IE6/7/8 backwards compatible so some things will have been removed.

Comment: Jeff, i know that jquery version is kinda old, but i only have the plugin working if i have the 1.8.3 librarie..

Comment: It will be a deprecated method, you can find it quite easily I'd imagine. Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: that's quite an old plugin too, I'm sure you can find a new one that uses jquery 2

Answer (score 1):

First the difference between jQuery 1 and 2 is the compatibility with older versions of Internet Explorer. So the best guess is, to use a CURRENT jQuery v1 version (1.11 at the moment).

However jQuery has changed a lot in version 1.9 which is probably the reason your old plugin fails if you remove 1.8. The only viable solution would be to update that plugin or change to another one if yours is not available anymore.

It is NEVER a good idea to use two versions of the same library in one project.

Comment: The thing that this plugin does everything that i needed..But i will try to search for a new one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery migrate plugin and migrate to 2.0.3 and then you can remove jquery 1.8.3.

Heres the [link for migration](http://jquery.com/download/)

its very simple and easy

Comment: Thanks!
I already solved in other way, but thanks everybody :)